# Deserialize JSON to different Object Types based on JSON content in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, object-type

So, I have developed an Azure Function triggered by IoT Hub in order to receive messages from devices.
And I want to deserialize them (messages received from devices as JSON) to different object types (obs. I am not allowed to change the syntax of messages). Is there a way I can deserialize into the correct object type, based on which message I receive?

- Scenario 1: If the message has the following syntax, then deserialization should be of type ReadResponseMessage.

  ```
  string JsonMessageFromDevice = "{"device_id":"DeviceTest","message_id":0,"port":3,"portValue":false,"time":"2021-08-25 10:18:51","response_status":"Send"}";
  ReadResponseMessage MessageReceivedType1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadResponseMessage>(JsonMessageFromDevice);
  ```
- Scenario 2: If the message has the following syntax, then deserialization should be of type EventMessage.

  ```
  string JsonMessageFromDevice = "{"device_id":"DeviceTest","message_id":1501,"port1":false,"port2":false,"time":"2021-08-25 10:22:02","response_status":"OK"}";
  EventMessage MessageReceivedType2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventMessage>(JsonMessageFromDevice);
  ```

Where:

```
class ReadResponseMessage  {
     
      [JsonProperty("device_id")]
      public string DeviceID {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("message_id")]
      public int MessageID {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("port")]
      public int Port{get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("portValue")]
      public bool PortValue {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("time")]
      public DateTime Time {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("response_status")]
      public string ResponseStatus{get; set;}
 
}
```

And:

```
class EventMessage {

      [JsonProperty("device_id")]
      public string DeviceID {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("message_id")]
      public int MessageID {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("port1")]
      public bool Port1{get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("port2")]
      public bool Port2 {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("time")]
      public DateTime Time {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("response_status")]
      public string ResponseStatus{get; set;}

}
```

Comment: Well, you just have to find the difference between the json strings and make a test for that. Then you can use the type you want. For instance: `if  (JsonMessageFromDevice.Contains("portValue")){ // use 'ReadResponseMessage '}`.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a long time solution because the number of messages and the complexity of the syntax will grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string JsonMessageFromDevice = "{"device_id":"DeviceTest","message_id":0,"port":3,"portValue":false,"time":"2021-08-25 10:18:51","response_status":"Send"}";

var oMycustomclassname = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonMessageFromDevice);
```

or

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(JsonMessageFromDevice);
   var result = jobject["port"];
   if (result != null)
   {
       ReadResponseMessage readResponseMessage = jobject.ToObject<ReadResponseMessage>();
   }
   else
   {
       EventMessage eventMessage = jobject.ToObject<EventMessage>();
   }
```

OR Change model

```
class ReadResponseMessage  {
     
      [JsonProperty("device_id")]
      public string DeviceID {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("message_id")]
      public int MessageID {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("port")]
      public Dictionary<String,bool> Port{get; set;} // or List<string> port

      [JsonProperty("time")]
      public DateTime Time {get; set;}

      [JsonProperty("response_status")]
      public string ResponseStatus{get; set;}
 
}
```

Comment: So how I will convert oMycustomclassname to ReadResponseMessage?

Comment: is this helpful? else please explain more what your issue

Comment: I has hopping to find a way to deserialize without interpreting values in JsonMessageFromDevice. The messages are more complex then showed here. Maybe if I find a way to cast the dynamic object to my object. But it's cool I have a solution for now. Thank you!

Comment: Okay i understand you now. Can you change the model that you have to a single class then add a property list <string>Ports